# How to remove other calendars from Office 365

Tags: 8.1, calendars, office

My phone shows calendars from O365 which have been deleted from the 'Other calendars' section on the O365 Calendar.

I accidently created a couple of calendars in O365 when trying to work out how the function worked (I should have used 'open' not 'new')

these newly created calendars are permanently stuck on my Nokia 930 (win 8.1, Lumia Denim), which is annoying.

I can delete them from the PC web browser looking at O365 Outlook.

I can untick them in the settings screen of the calendar app, but they never disappear from that settings list.

I tried deleting my 0365 account from my phone and reinstating it including a power down in between.

Any ideas how to get of rid of these? they're cluttering up the settings screen!

screengrab of new calendar option in PC browser O365 with calendar app settings screen[image: screengrab of new calendar option in PC browser O365 with calendar app settings screen]

Comment: I would've expected them to disappear from your phone once they're deleted from the Office 365 servers - although your screen shot still shows the calendar as alive and well on there?

Comment: Rowland - exactly, you would expect it to go, wouldn't you! but it doesn't.

Comment: ps it's not a time cache thing either (they have been there for some months, irritating me) @RowlandShaw

Comment: When did you try to remove them from your Office365 account?

Answer (score 4):

Found this thread a little late and not sure if this will help, but....

After 2 hours of trial and error I managed to remove the rouge calendars from Lumia 930 phone.

Logged into Microsoft Outlook Exchange.

Accessed *Folder* view

Permanently deleted calendars from trash (for some reason the calendars did not show in the trash while in *Mail* view)

Next on the Lumia 930, went to *All Settings* > *email+accounts* > *Exchange Account* > *sync*.

(Sync failed the first time and I had to re-enter my password.)

And as an extra last step, I restarted my phone.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you...you saved my hours...I too did it from Outlook Exchange and wonder the feature is not present in Office 365 itself

Answer (score 0):

My account was recently migrated off Exchange to Office365 cloud, so I could not find a way to access "Microsoft Outlook Exchange" [as suggested by Sara](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/12459).
However, I found a solution by opening Outlook 2013 on a desktop machine and was able to delete the calendar there.